# How can store all values to a class object injected from dagger2?

Tags: java, android, singleton, pass-by-reference, dagger-2

Below is the LoginActivity class

```
@Inject
User injectedUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login2);

    MyApp.getComponent(this).inject(this); // injection completed here
}


@Subscribe public void onLoginCompleted(UserResultEvent event) 
{

    Log.e(" Finding ", injectedUser.getAuthTokenWebService());

    User user       =   event.user;
    injectedUser    =   user;  // injectedUser looses values for next activity


    // By setting each value as shown in given below two lines, 
    //I am able to get values on another activity, in my case, DashBoard class

    //injectedUser.setAuthTokenWebService(user.getAuthTokenWebService());
    //injectedUser.setUserId(user.getUserId());



    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Below is my simple Dagger Module class

```
@Module
public class MyAppModule
{
    private final MyApp app;

    public MyAppModule(MyApp app) {     this.app = app;       }

    @Provides @Singleton MyApp provideMyApp() {  return app;   }

    @Provides @Singleton
    Application provideApplication(MyApp app) {       return app;        }

    // getting User Object
    @Provides @Singleton  
    User provideUser(){   return new User(); }
}
```

and my last Dashboard activity class is

```
@Inject
User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.dashb_main);

     MyApp.getComponent(this).inject(this);

     // Here is the problem,  
     Log.e("Dashboard ", String.valueOf(user.getAuthTokenWebService())); 
}
```

---

```
Log.e("Dashboard ", String.valueOf(user.getAuthTokenWebService()));
```

gives me the default value of AuthToken, but it should print different value as it is set in LoginActivity class i.e  `injectedUser    =   user;`
But this line has no effect as injectedUser variable does not retain values for the next activity, however it is set singleton in the dagger providerUser method.

I do not want to set each value got from web service by typing code as shown below

```
injectedUser.setAuthTokenWebService(user.getAuthTokenWebService()); 
injectedUser.setUserId(user.getUserId());
```

It works this way but is there any other way that injectedUser can have same values of User object fetched from service or i have to set each value as shown above ?

Comment: I found a hack... that i,. Create User reference in User Class and set and get User by setter or getter or pass it in constructor User(new User())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it "loses values", [you're just altering the pointer to the User object, and not the User object itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

You'd need to provide a holder.

```
public class UserHolder {
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Module
public class MyAppModule {
    //...
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public UserHolder userHolder(User user) {
         UserHolder userHolder = new UserHolder();
         userHolder.setUser(user);
         return userHolder;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public User user() {
         return new User();
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Inject
UserHolder userHolder;

Log.e("Dashboard ", String.valueOf(userHolder.getUser().getAuthTokenWebService()));
```

And

```
@Inject
UserHolder userHolder;

@Subscribe public void onLoginCompleted(UserResultEvent event) {

    Log.e(" Finding ", userHolder.getUser().getAuthTokenWebService());

    User user       =   event.user;
    userHolder.setUser(user);
```